# Can regression forecasts of univariate time series be independent (of one another)

Tags: regression, time-series, forecasting, fourier-transform, forecast-combination

Suppose I have short-term forecasts from two univarite regression models of the same time series.  I am choosing the models to be as different as possible in structure and assumptions. For instance, one may be an autoregression and the other fits a set of Fourier terms. Both models use only lags or transformed lags of the dependent variable as independent variables.

Is it likely that the two forecasts will be independent? Is it *possible*?

I am trying to understand why the average of several forecasts is often better than the individual forecasts, and whether there is anything I can do to make that more likely to be true, or true to a greater extent. It seems like the average should be better than the component forecasts if the components have expected value equal to the future value, variances are comparable in magnitude,  and the forecasts are independent.

Comment: They are functions of the same data, so I do not think they can be independent. E.g. if there is a data entry error, all models and their forecasts will be affected. I take that to imply dependence.

Comment: If you really can find *independent* time series model predictions to form the ensemble average which per central limit theorem follows a Gaussian distribution thus is "better" in the sense of normality, while each individual model prediction may not have such normality. In practice they may not even need to be strictly independent.

Comment: Note that the variance reduction effect of averaging doesn't require independence of, in your example, the forecasts.   It only requires that the forecasts aren't perfectly correlated.

Answer (score 0):

If two regression models of the same time series are trained on the same set of data, then the forecasts generated by these models are dependent on one another as both models are likely to have learned similar patterns from the data.

To try to make these two short-term regression models statistically independent in your scenario is to fit your models on different training sets of the same sample dataset, for instance, to use different periods of the same underlying time series or to split your time series into two sequence parts each of which is to be fed to different model, then the forecasts generated by these models would be possibly independent.

If each model is accurate and independent then averaging them together will likely result in improved overall forecast accurate with reduced variance, in the same fashion as [random forest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_forest) ensemble method. On the other hand, if the individual models are themselves inaccurate, then averaging them may not result in a significant improvement in accuracy.

Comment: A small thing: In a random forest, trees are trained on the same dataset, so the constituents of the ensemble are not independent. Bagging goes a bit further by training trees on different bootstrap samples, but each bootstrap sample is based on the same original sample, so the dependence is not avoided there either.

Comment: @RichardHardy thx for your small note. These seem like cases of the *exactly wrong, approximately right* nature.